# Why do results differ when training DCGAN on TF 2.0 vs 1.15?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been testing different architectures and parameters for training a DCGAN recently. In the past, when I used TensorFlow 1.15, I had a lot of success getting the generated images to look like my desired output, but on 2.0 the results are completely different even though I train using the exact same code and images. For instance, here is the output at 1400 epochs on version 1.15:

[image: 1400 Epochs on TF 1.15]

And here is the output at 1400 epochs on version 2.0:

[image: 1400 Epochs on TF 2.0]

On TF 2.0, the accuracy of the discriminator quickly goes to 1.0, and the generator slowly increases. On 1.15, the accuracy of the discriminator hovers around 0.6 and the generator around 0.2.

Some things I have tried:

- Adjusting discriminator and generator learning rate
- Training the generator more than the discriminator
- Training the discriminator more than the generator
- Altering discriminator architecture

I am assuming there is something simple I have missed between the two versions. I have been training with Python on Jupyter notebook on GCP, and primarily use the Keras API (tf.keras). Any help appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to run both versions with all the random seeds set to a fixed value?
For example something like `tf.random.set_seed(1234)` and `np.random.seed(1234)` ?

Comment: Yes, but the results still look the same